# Extracting Rows Based On Search Criteria

Tags: excel, vba, copy, extract

My issue is that I am trying to extract some information from a very large data sheet. The information that is being extracted is based on some search criteria that is entered on a form. The search form counts how many occurrences of this criteria exist, but then I need to extract the individual rows into a second sheet.

The bit I'm having difficulty with is understanding how to actually structure the extraction code. I'm in need of being pointed in the right direction. If the code can count how many occurrences there are, surely I can get the row numbers for those occurrences and extract the information, I'm just not getting anywhere trying to figure it out.

Here's my SEARCH code (this code **works** to get the number of occurrences based on the criteria asked)

```
Public Sub Run_Count_Click()

'// Set Ranges
Dim Cr_1, CR1_range, _
Cr_2, CR2_range, _
Cr_3, CR3_range, _
Cr_4, CR4_range, _
Cr_5, CR5_range _
As Range

'// Set Integers
Dim CR1, V1, CR1_Result, _
CR2, V2, CR2_Result, _
CR3, V3, CR3_Result, _
CR4, V4, CR4_Result, _
CR5, V5, CR5_Result, _
total_result, _
total_result2, _
total_result3, _
total_result4, _
total_result5 _
As Integer

'Set Strings
Dim V_1, V_2, V_3, V_4, V_5 As String

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("database")

Sheets("Settings").Range("Start_Date").Value = Format(Me.R_Start.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
Sheets("Settings").Range("End_Date").Value = Format(Me.R_End.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")

'Collect Start & End Dates
Dim dStartDate As Long
Dim dEndDate As Long
dStartDate = Sheets("Settings").Range("Start_Date").Value
dEndDate = Sheets("Settings").Range("End_Date").Value

ws.Activate

On Error GoTo error_Sdate:
Dim RowNum As Variant
    RowNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(dStartDate, Range("B1:B60000"), 0)
     'MsgBox "Found " & Format(dStartDate, "dd/mm/yyyy") & " at row : " & RowNum

On Error GoTo error_Edate:
Dim RowNumEnd As Variant
    RowNumEnd = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(dEndDate, Range("B1:B60000"), 1)
    ' MsgBox "Found " & Format(dEndDate, "dd/mm/yyyy") & " at row : " & RowNumEnd

GoTo J1

error_Sdate:

Dim msg As String

msg = "You entered " & Format(dStartDate, "dd/mm/yyyy") & " as your Start Date, but no referrals were made on that date"
msg = msg & vbCrLf & "Please enter a different date in the Start Date box"
MsgBox msg, , "Start Date Not Found"
Err.Clear
Exit Sub

error_Edate:
msg = "You entered " & Format(dEndDate, "dd/mm/yyyy") & " as your End Date, but no referrals were made on that date"
msg = msg & vbCrLf & "Please enter a different date in the End Date box"
MsgBox msg, , "End Date Not Found"
Err.Clear
Exit Sub


J1:


'// Get Criteria From Form And Search Database Headers
Set Cr_1 = ws.Cells.Find(What:=Me.Count_Criteria_1.Value, After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), MatchCase:=False)

If Not Cr_1 Is Nothing Then

CR1 = Cr_1.Column '//Set CR1 as the Column in which the Criteria Header was found

Else
    MsgBox "Criteria 1 Has Not Been Found In The Database. Report Has Failed To Generate"
    Exit Sub
End If

'// Get Variable Value From Form And Set Shortcode
V_1 = Me.Criteria_1_Variable.Value

Set CR1_range = ws.Range(ws.Cells(RowNum, CR1), ws.Cells(RowNumEnd, CR1))
CR1_Result = Application.CountIf(CR1_range, V_1)

Me.Count_Result.visible = True

Me.Count_Result.Value = "Based On Your Search Criteria Of:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"- " & Me.Count_Criteria_1.Value & ": " & Me.Criteria_1_Variable.Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"The Results Are: " & CR1_Result & " entries found between the dates " & Format(dStartDate, "dd/mm/yyyy") & _
" and " & Format(dEndDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")





Exit Sub
```

Is there an easy way of doing this with a loop? I know loops are not the best way of handling things, but Im looking for anything that works and I can tweak to suit my needs.

Thanks if you can help in advance, it's a monster of a spreadsheet!

**----------------------------**
**Update With Accepted Answer:**
**----------------------------**

```
Public Sub Count_Extract_Click()

'Collect Information To Be Extracted
Set ws = Worksheets("database")
Set ps = Worksheets("Extracted Rows")

   ps.Range("A3:AM60000").Clear


For i = RowNum To RowNumEnd
   If ws.Cells(i, CR1).Value = V_1 Then

   ws.Range("A" & i & ":AM" & i).Copy

   ps.Activate


   'find first empty row in database
emR = ps.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1


ps.Range("A" & emR & ":AM" & emR).PasteSpecial

   End If
Next i

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to set a For loop to check each value in the range you've found and copy it to (another cell, an array, whatever you like.)

```
For i = rowNum To rowNumEnd
   If Cells(i,CR1).Value = V_1 Then
      MsgBox "Found match on row " & i
   End If
Next i
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work.  Let me know if you get any errors.

Comment: Thanks, works flawlessly. I had to declare my variables outside of the routine so they could share information, but apart from that it was a straight forward copy and paste. Excellent, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I can't really try this out, but maybe you can. Keep the line `V_1 = Me.Criteria_1_Variable.Value` but replace the next 2 by :

```
CR1_Result = 0 'Initiates counter at 0
Dim CR1_Lines(1000) As Long 'Declares an array of 1001 (indexes 0-1000) Longs (big integers) 

For x = RowNum To RowNumEnd 'Loops through all the rows of CR1

    If ws.Cells(x, CR1) = V_1 Then 'Match!

        'Double array size if capacity is reached
        If CR1_Result = UBound(CR1_Lines) Then
            ReDim Presrve CR1_Lines(UBound(CR1_Lines) * 2)
        End If

        'Store that line number in the array
        CR1_Lines(CR1_Result) = x 

        'Increment count of matches
        CR1_Result = CR1_Result + 1 

    End If

Next x 'Next row!
```

You can then loop through that array with this code :

```
For i = 0 to UBound(CR1_Lines)
    'Do something! (Why not just an annoying pop-up box with the content!)
     MsgBox CR1_Lines(i)
Next i
```

**EDIT :** I just read that the spreadsheet is monstruous, and re-dimensioning every time a new match is found might be neat, but it's a hell of a performance drop. I made some changes directly in the above code to make it somewhat more effective.

**EDIT #2 :** I've simplified code so you don't have anything to do but a copy paste (please forgive me not assuming RowNum and RowNumEnd had valid data). It should work exactly as accepted answer, but was posted a bit before and actually shows how to extract the line number. I understand if all you needed is a pop-up box with the line number, and will be satisfied with the upvote already received.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I will need to edit my code too much to get this to work. There are multiple criteria (CR#) and variables (V_#) in the worksheet. so I need a nice easy insertable code such as the accepted answer. Thanks for your answer, I've marked it as useful

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I have tested and it does work. Shame I can't accept two answers.